# Python Stop Generator Gracefully

Tags: python

I have a generator in python that returns rows from a postgres table. After those rows are processed I want to delete those rows, but not until they are successfully processed by the process being yielded to.

```
def scan():
  rows = # ... get rows from pg

  yield rows
 
  delete(rows)
```

In my process that uses the generator, I want to stop the scan prematurely if a condition is met (i.e. a process has run too long)

```
timeout = 60
start = time.time()

for rows in scan():
  do_something_with_rows(rows)

  if time.time() - start > timeout:
    # Break out of generator gracefully
```

If I `return` or `break` here, the generator will never delete the rows. If I throw a `StopIteration` here, it just behaves as an exception being thrown.

Is it possible to break out of a generator gracefully, so that the generator will complete it's final post-yield process?

**Edit:**

Figured it out. You can catch a GeneratorException.
See: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/generatorexit

Comment: You can use scan().close() to exit the generator. It will throw an `GeneratorExit`. You can catch it to do something if you want. Otherwise it will be handled by python automatically.

Comment: @Goion just tested it and it does not continue from the yield of the last generator. I'm looking for a solution that finishes the generator function after the yield when i exit early

Comment: how about copy rows-delete rows-yield rows_copy?

Comment: Isn't that what try: finally: is for?  The finally section always runs.  Return or exception.. it always runs.

Comment: Why do you have a generator that always yields exactly once?  It sounds like it wants to be a context manager or something.

Comment: @DavisHerring you're seeing the trees for the forrest. this sample code is demonstrating a behavior that i'm trying to work around and not actually copy-pasted from my production environment. in reality, this generator yields many rows :)

Comment: @micah: Well, it’s easier to see what to do if the example is realistic (especially if an XY problem pertains): here it seems to be yielding all the rows at once (as a list?), which is not a simplification of yielding them one at a time.  In this case it also probably matters if the generator performs non-trivial work after the first yield and before the deletion epilog.

Comment: @DavisHerring I figured the non-trivial nature of the work after the first yield was implied by the fact that I wanted to ensure the post-yield work was still being completed. But you're not alone in assuming it wasn't

Answer (score 2):

You can catch a `GeneratorExit` exception from a break in the yielded-to process and perform any post-yield actions.

Details:
https://www.peterbe.com/plog/generatorexit